# Selenium. Почему выбрасывает NoSuchElementException?

Tags: python, selenium

мне надо спарсить данные с сайта, запускаю двайвер, делаю все укладываясь в 30 сек(ввести hash, указать кол-во раундов, дождаться когда все загрузится), в итоге все выглядит так (prnt.sc/wft0xn).
Все вроде хорошо, но выбрасывает NoSuchElementException, хотя все верно указано, пробовал дожидаться через явное ожидание, пока страница загрузит хотя-бы 1 элемент, но он также не видел, хотя все было уже на экране и выбрасывал ошибку, пробовал 2-мя разными способами указывать xpath путь, но тоже NoSuch.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://jsfiddle.net/Dexon95/2fmuxLza/show")

sleep(30)

# 53b25a504ddd78121e6473bfc870d3390f32292e35c0bf7a638ef16d8304e45e

a = 1

while True:
    # element = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/section/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]"))) # ждет загрузки страницы
    try:
        Hash = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="game_verify_table"]/tr[{a}]/td[1]').text
        print(Hash)
        Hash = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'/html/body/section/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[{a}]/td[1]').text
        print(Hash)
        game = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="game_verify_table"]/tr[{a}]/td[2]').text
        print(game)
        game = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'/html/body/section/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[{a}]/td[2]').text
        print(game)

        t = [str(a), 'game', '{};'.format(game), '{}'.format(Hash)]
        print(t)
        
        a += 1
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        print('исключение1')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('исключение2')
```

Comment: Кажется, как страница не обновляется после нажатия run this fiddle, как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, оказывается надо было просто переключиться на iframe

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="result"]/iframe'))
```